# Split 6 slides per page to 1 slide per page (PDF or XPS)

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF (or XPS if it helps) with 6 slides per page and I want to split it in a PDF with 1 slide per page.

At the moment there are 3 pages with 16 slides. After the split I want to have 16 pages.

**How is this possible?**

Already tried:

- Bliss does a poor job (none) at aligning (the same on every page).
- Adobe Acrobat DC Crop works only for one slide per page => not an option
- Poster print in Adobe Acrobat does only work for 2 slides on 1 page

Comment: You mean "sides" or slides"? 6 sides per page doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, i have edited my question.

Comment: Do you still have the original presentation file? If so what format was it in?

Comment: No, it's about slides our prof's give us.